# getElementsByTagName multiple campo

Tags: javascript

La adaptación de código era crear otra variable con la misma función y se me paso por alto gracias a @BDOM, espero que a alguien más les sea de utilidad.

Ahora, existe mejor forma de adaptar el código que sea más correcta?

Código en funcionamiento:

```js
  function Searchcamp() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, ts, i;
  input = document.getElementById("camp0");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    ts = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td && ts) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 || ts.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="camp0" onkeyup="Searchcamp()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:10%;">ID</th>
    <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usando [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) resulta más sencillo, te dejo un ejemplo de lo que querés hacer haciendo una búsqueda global en todos los `td`, excepto el primero. Más que nada lo utilizo por el selector que tiene, es parecido al selector de `CSS`.

```js
// función Searchcamp
function Searchcamp() {
  // "this" es el elmento en el que fue llamado
  var input = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
  
  // obtengo los tr que vienen después del primero
  // así evito que entre el ID, Name y Country
  $('#myTable tr + tr').each(function(index) {
    // asigno this con tr y oculto todos
    var tr = $(this);
    tr.css('display', 'none');
    
    $(this).find('td').each(function(index) {
      var tdText = $(this).text().toUpperCase();
      
      // si tiene un valor existente, muestro el tr
      if (tdText.indexOf(input) > -1) {
        tr.css('display', '');
      }
    });
  });
}

// Un vez que esté listo el DOM
$(document).ready(function() {
  // asigno el evento "keyup" al input
  $('#camp0').on('keyup', Searchcamp);
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="camp0" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name" />

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:10%;">ID</th>
    <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: He analizado tu código y se ve más sencillo pero cómo puedo hacer para que filtre las columnas que quiero como en el código que he añadido arriba, ya que hace búsqueda en todas las columnas.

Comment: Ah, vos querés buscar de algunas columnas en particular como la de `ID` y `Name`? En ese caso, lo único que deberías cambiar es el selector para que tome sólo esos dos. En vez de `$(this).find('td')`, deberías hacer `$(this).find('td:nth(0), td:nth(1)')`. En ese caso toma el primer td y el segundo.

Comment: ahí si quedo funcionando como necesitaba no sabía que era tan sencillo. Muchas gracias.

Comment: De nada, no olvides de marcar como correcta la respuesta. Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

Edito mi anterior respuesta para crear una que este mas de acuerdo a lo que pides.

```
var indexCols = [0,1,2,3];
Searchcamp(indexCols);

function Searchcamp(indexCols) {    
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
    input = document.getElementById("camp0");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("table");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {               
        for(z=0; z<indexCols.length; z++){        
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[indexCols[z]];    
            if (td) {
                if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

He hecho que cuando llames a la funcion le envies un array de las columnas que quieres filtrar, en este caso esta el `td[0]`,`td[1]`,`td[2]`y`td[3]` pero podria ser cualquier `td` y tantos como quieras.
Por lo tanto para buscar la columnas 3 y 4 deberias ejecutar:

```
var indexCols = [2,3]
Searchcamp(indexCols) ;
```

No olvides que los arrays se empiezan a contar desde 0 por lo que la columna 1 es la posicion 0 del array.

Comment: no sé si me explique bien y si lo respondí bien. El resumen es que filtra a getElementsByTagName("td")[2] y quisiera que filtrase por ejemplo getElementsByTagName("td")[2] y getElementsByTagName("td")[3]

Comment: Pero ya sabes cuales son los indices que quieres filtrar "2" y "3" o no?
Si ya sabes como son seria hacer 
`td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
td2=tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3];
if (td&&td2) {...}`

Comment: Voy a editar el codigo para que se haga de otra forma

Comment: @Vicente he modificado el código

Comment: he editado mi mensaje con un ejemplo  de lo que em mencionastes antes no lo hago correr bien, y tu ejemplo último me da error no se a que se deba puedes ponerlo en funcionamiento.

Answer (score 3):

Utiliza la condición OR (`||`) en tu `if` para especificar múltiples filtros por columna:

```
  function Searchcamp() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, ts, i;
  input = document.getElementById("camp0");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    ts = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td && ts) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 || ts.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
```

Tomé el código de tu segundo JS para probar y funciona correctamente.

Espero sea de ayuda.

Comment: Perfecto, se me paso por alto adaptar la parte que mencionaste del modo que indicas funciona correctamente no había pensado en copiar toda la linea. Hay alguna otra forma más optimizada para el código o lo ves bien así?